Is there a way to allow a non root user to run netplan apply without sudo?
I'm developing a Django project and I was asked to implement a functionality that allows the admin users to change the ips on the yaml file of the hosting server, so far I manage to do so by using subprocess.run(['sudo', 'netplan', 'apply']) but I was told I shouldn't be using sudo in this case. I've tried doing a pkla file and editing the sudoers, but nothing seems to be working. I am getting this error:
ERROR: cannot create file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service: Failed to create file “/run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service.FRGUT2”: Permission denied
Any thoughts about this?

That would be to easy to abuse by people that should not be able to.
I would set this up so those users edit a copy of the netplan config file. Set that file up with the correct permissions and have the system take care of placing the file in the correct place (could be a cronjob).
Do it with a script so you can (for instance) make a backup of the original file or so it restart the service so the new config is used.

Well, the class I am developing takes care of creating a backup file of the current yaml and then the yaml is edited through the webpage (only the administrators can do this, btw), it is saved and then a button trigers the command sudo netplan apply, the thing is I was told not to run the command with sudo, I am running out of ideas. I will do a research about the cronjob stuff, never used it before. Thank you for your time! :D

Replace the command with a simple touch of a pid file on the server and a crontab task on the server to check a change of the timestamp of that file and if so copy the file over from the server.
